# org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 09050000 GetModelsDiff return status is 404 while running the Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, spring-bean

I have imported a maven project from git hub and followed the instructions given in its README file to run Alfresco. While testing the application I have entered  http://localhost:8080/share/  for which I am successfully getting the login page for Alfresco. But when I am giving the default username and password I am not able to login to the application. Getting an error *"Your authentication details have not been recognized or Alfresco may not be available at this time."* When I checked the console and the Alfresco log file,  I found `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` followed by `org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 09050000` GetModelsDiff return status is 404.

**Installed the following:**

1. Apache Tomcat 7.0 version
2. PostgreSQL 9.4
3. Also installed few dependencies needed for the project(Elastic Search6.4 and ActiveMQ5.0).

Working on Java8.

Github repository link of the imported project: GitHub - Open-MBEE/mms: Model Management System

Below is the exceptions observed in the console

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-10-05 13:25:28,063  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Using database URL 'jdbc:h2:C:\Users\alien147\git\mms_modified\mms-ent/alf_data_dev/h2_data/alf_dev;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;MVCC=FALSE;LOCK_MODE=0' with user 'alfresco'.
 2018-10-05 13:25:28,065  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Connected to database H2 version 1.4.190 (2015-10-11)
 2018-10-05 13:25:32,648  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
 2018-10-05 13:25:32,648  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.1-metadata-query-indexes
 2018-10-05 13:25:38,538  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
 2018-10-05 13:25:38,715  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1] complete
 2018-10-05 13:25:40,942  WARN  [context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [localhost-startStop-1] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emsConfig' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/mms-amp/context/mms-init-service-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at gov.nasa.jpl.view_repo.util.EmsConfig.setProperties(EmsConfig.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.doInvoke(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:152)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
    ... 22 more


 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 09050000 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1157)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:249)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:207)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.ensureFirstModelSync(ModelTracker.java:229)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.registerForCore(CoreWatcherJob.java:131)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.execute(CoreWatcherJob.java:74)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

Can anyone please help me out in solving the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The alfresco WAR and share WAR are completely separate. It is quite common for the share WAR to start up and show the login page while the back-end it talks to (the alfresco WAR) has failed to start.

That's what is happening in this case. It appears that the emsConfig bean, defined in https://github.com/Open-MBEE/mms/blob/develop/mms-ent/repo-amp/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/module/mms-amp/context/mms-init-service-context.xml, is getting a null pointer, probably because it cannot find that properties file.

Answer (score 0):

On the [installation instructions for this project](https://github.com/Open-MBEE/mms/blob/develop/mms-ent/docs/SingleServerDeploy.md#installing-mms) it is written :
"Create and edit the mms.properties file in the $TOMCAT_HOME/shared/classes directory (You can copy mms-ent/mms.properties.example)".

Have you performed this step ?

Comment: Hi, I have performed the instructions mentioned at https://github.com/Open-MBEE/mms under README.md as I am working on Windows OS for this project and not on CentOS 7.x. I have followed the same instructions as mentioned in the README.md file.